# Is there a special procedure for mid-air refueling in the rain?

Tags: military, weather, mid-air-refueling

After reading about [mid-air refueling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_refueling) and watching [The Perfect Storm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Perfect_Storm_(film)), I have a question: is there a special procedure to observe when performing an in-flight refueling in the rain?

Side note: I heard the tanker pilot says something like "we have a wet hose". Is this phrase common?

Comment: "wet hose" probably means that there is fuel in the hose (which people should be aware of) rather than being wet from rain.

Comment: There is a procedure: don't.

Comment: It always helps to add to questions like this, **why** you think that there might be something different.  Rain is rain, but not all rain is equal.

Comment: @GdD I realise that was a comment rather than an answer but, still, more detail would be helpful.

Comment: @simon maybe increase risk of gusting in the rain require extra care? Maybe a condition not known by non pilot like me :)

Comment: Air refueling in many cases is done at an altitude above any weather, so this is only rarely a factor, if ever

Comment: @SSumner the case I saw in the movie was **under** weather. I agree they prefer to do it above weather but when they have no choice and have to do it below? Anything special for that?

Comment: Refuuuuuueling in the raaaaain...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're [VMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_meteorological_conditions) and simply have rain falling, the procedure doesn't change, and it isn't a big deal (talking fixed wing refueling with a boom here; other communities' procedures/capabilities may be different).  The receiver's windshield will have some amount of rain hitting it, but if it isn't particularly heavy rain then he should still be able to do the AR.

If the visibility is really bad because of the rain, or if you're getting into [IMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_meteorological_conditions), then that's the situation you have, irrespective of rain falling or not, and obviously you'd rather have better conditions for doing the refueling.  Going IMC momentarily while you're hooked up may not be a big deal, as you can still see the tanker, but if you lose sight then the first priority is to get positive separation between the two aircraft.

Answer (score 5):

The procedure is no different to if it's not raining unless the rain is heavy enough to impair the visibilty from the receiver aircrafts cockpit.

Air to Air refuelling is normally planned to be carried out above cloud but there may be operational reasons to do it elsewhere

The terms wet and dry refer to whether fuel is flowing or not.  A wet contact is one where the receiver receives fuel from the tanker.  A dry contact is one where contact is made but no fuel is transferred, this is done for training as the process of making and breaking contact needs to be practiced